# Simple Linq grouping

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

how to use `group by` in Linq.

SqlServer Sample

```
select 
    ActionGroupName,  
    sum(cast(isnull(solicit_count,0) as int)) as 'SolicitCount' 
from 
    [solicits]
group by
    ActionGroupName
```

my linq version

```
var groupbyfilter = from v in lstSale
                    group v by v.ActionGroupName into g
                    select g.ActionGroupName, sum(g.solicit_count)
```

i am not getting it in proper way.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
var groupbyfilter = from v in lstSale
                    group v by v.ActionGroupName into g
                    select new 
                    { 
                      ActionGroupName = g.Key, 
                      Sum = g.Sum(x => x.solicit_count)
                    };
```